# How to map JSON keys with non-alphanumeric characters in Django Rest Framework Serializer

Tags: python, json, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have some JSON keys that contain non-alphanumeric characters e.g. `"my-key="`

I need to map this key to a field `my_key` in my Django model.

The traditional way to do this is to add a custom field to the `ModelSerializer` where you specify the `source`:

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    my_key= = serializers.CharField(source='my_key')

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('my-key=',)
```

However this obviously doesn't work because:

```
my_key= = serializers.CharField(source='my_key')
```

is not valid python for declaring an attribute.

**How do I map my JSON key to the model field?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will use these two methods of serializer offered by DRF:

`.to_representation()` - Override this to support serialization, for read operations. Make mapping from `django_legit_name` to `django-not-legit-field-name`

`.to_internal_value()` - Override this to support deserialization, for write operations. Make mapping from `django-not-legit-field-name` to `django_legit_name`

Examples you can find here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.0-announcement/#serializers

Answer (score 2):

Just create a custom metaclass for your serializer:

```
class CustomMetaClass(serializers.SerializerMetaclass):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        custom_fields_mapping = attrs.get('custom_fields_mapping')

        if custom_fields_mapping:
            for label, value in custom_fields_mapping.items():
                if attrs.get(label):
                    attrs[value] = attrs.pop(label)
        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
```

And use it like this:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer, metaclass=CustomMetaClass):
    custom_fields_mapping = {"my_field": "$_my_field"}

    my_field = serializers.CharField()
```

It will produce the following serializer:

```
In [2]: MySerializer()
Out[2]: 
MySerializer():
    $_my_field = CharField()
```